# Can the following class be better generified?

Tags: java, generics

I wrote this class which uses a lot of generics. Unfortunately, some of the generics I had to left with `Object` because the type is dynamic. I can't use the `<?>` capture either and end with a cast to `<Object, Object>` from a more specific typing. This gives me a warning of unchecked cast even though everything extends Object. Here is the code:

```
public class EventBus {
  // Ideally I would like something like:
  // Map<Class<EventType>, Map<Handler, BiConsumer<Handler, EventType>>>
  // So that it is guaranteed that the BiConsumer types are going to match the ones in
  // the map keys. but the maps should be able to handle multiple types of handlers and
  // events, so I can't generify the class itself, nor the field.
  private final Map<Class<?>, Map<Object, BiConsumer<Object, Object>>> mSubscribers
      = new HashMap<>();

  public <Handler, EventType> void register(Class<EventType> type,
                                            Handler handler,
                                            BiConsumer<Handler, EventType> function) {
    var subscribers = mSubscribers.computeIfAbsent(type, x -> new LinkedHashMap<>());

    // Casting the BiConsumer here is unnecessary in my view.
    // But it gives error otherwise and even with the cast, it gives me a warning.
    // If I change the BiConsumer to <?, ?> i can remove this cast. but then the post
    // method throws error.
    subscribers.put(handler, (BiConsumer<Object, Object>) function);
  }

  public void unregister(Class<?> type, Object handler) {
    var subscribers = mSubscribers.get(type);
    if (subscribers == null || subscribers.remove(handler) == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("handler is not registered to this event"));
    }
  }

  // This event is Object because that is what the BiConsumer is expecting.
  // I don't get much by generifying this parameter.
  void post(Object event) {
    var type = event.getClass();
    var eventSubscribers = mSubscribers.get(type);
    if (eventSubscribers == null || eventSubscribers.isEmpty()) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("No handler registered for this event"));
    }
    for (var eventSubscriberEntry : eventSubscribers.entrySet()) {
      var function = eventSubscriberEntry.getValue();
      var handler = eventSubscriberEntry.getKey();
      // If I change the BiConsumer to <?, ?> the following line throws error because
      // Object is not compatible with capture<?>. although "?" should be anything that
      // inherits from Object, including Object. so not sure why it would give me error.
      function.accept(handler, event);
    }
  }
}
```

The way I would use the class is this:

```
public class State
  private final EventBus mEventBus;

  public State(EventBus eventBus) {
    mEventBus = eventBus;
  }

  public void onInitialize() {
    // I can't use 'this::onMyEvent' because then I can't pass 'this' (nor
    // 'this::onMyEvent') in the unregister method, since the functional interface
    // instances would be different.
    mEventBus.register(MyEvent.class, this, State::onMyEvent);
  }

  public void onDestroy() {
    mEventBus.unregister(MyEvent.class, this);
  }

  private void onMyEvent(MyEvent event) {
    //Do something
  }
}
```

I saw the code in guava's EventBus and they are using reflection to call the methods so they know the method they are calling comes from the right instance and don't require the BiConsumer check. They also have a subscriber class that wraps the handler and the method in a single object. But then, when you unregister a handler, they have to reparse the class to see the annotated methods again and create new subscriber objects in memory to then compare them to the ones in the map (with an overriden hashcode and equals methods) and remove them. That is very inefficient and would prefer to avoid it.

I welcome refactoring ideas. Or if this really is the best I can get with Generics, then I will continue with this design.

Thanks.

Comment: You can change the `<Object, Object>` to `<?,?>` everywhere, and **only** need to cast when calling the function eventually (so there you cast it with something like `BiConsumer<Object, Object> typedFunction = (BiConsumer<Object, Object>) function;`). The type safety is guaranteed by the `register` method. BTW: This is only a comment, and not an answer, because I think you should consider posting this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hmmm, I'll try that. Didn't know about code review stack exchange. They open a exchange for everything now! XD

Comment: So basically I change to <?,?> and move the cast from the register function to the post function. I wonder though why I can't use ? for the handler as well and only for the biconsumer.